# Assigning an automatic ID

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I'm trying to add data to my firebase database. But how do i automatic assign the next available ID to the data i'm trying to send?

I added the following data automatic via Json import:
[image]

But whenever i try to add data, and i leave the ID empty i get the following result:

[image]

When i add the ID manually inside my code, it does work! but how can i make it it does this automatic for me?

Here is my fire service.ts

```
 create(id: string, description: string, kind: string, name: string, preparation: string, img: string, ingredients: string) {
this.db.object('gerechten/'+id).update({
  id:id,
  description: description,
  kind: kind,
  name: name,
  preparation: preparation,
  img: img,
  ingredients: ingredients
})
```

}

and my create.ts

```
  gerecht = {
    description: "",
    kind: "",
    name: "",
    prepartion: "",
    ingredients: "",
    id: "",
    img: ""
  }
---------

  create() {
    this.db.create(this.gerecht.id, this.gerecht.description, this.gerecht.kind, this.gerecht.name, this.gerecht.prepartion, this.gerecht.img, this.gerecht.ingredients) 
    this.navCtrl.push(HomePage)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside **create()** method first you have to get **last node** from gerechten, then get the key of object and convert key into integer. after increase the key by adding 1 and pass value into **this.db.create()** method.

[Get Last node using limitToLast(1))](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Query#limitToLast)

Comment: It all works, but when i add an item. the ID does not refresh. i need to log out and re-log my app to make it reset

Comment: what you meant by saying it all works?  did you use my way or your way? @Ramon